# How to automate Flash based pages using selenium webdriver

Tags: flash, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am a tester. We use one tool which contains pages developed using Flash. I need to automate few tasks which are repetitive for our testing purpose. I have knowledge on Selenium Web driver. But i am unable to inspect any element on those flash pages. Kindly help me in solving this problem.

Answer (score 6):

I've played with [Flash Selenium](https://code.google.com/archive/p/flash-selenium/) before.

It also depends on your project but here are some links to get you started doing some research.

Directly from source: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/flash_selenium.html

http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/testing-flash-selenium-flash-javascript-communication/

http://automationmentor.blogspot.com/2014/08/automating-flash-applications-and.html

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by using Neoload. Then I could record my browsing flow (even though this is a webpage base on flash) web page browsing. https://www.neotys.com/blog/

I did not like the experience working with this tool but it solved my problem. To bad it is licence product. This might be a problem if you plan to use this in a CI/CD system with a low budget.

Answer (score 0):

Using sikulix-api did the work for me.

After the standard selenium setup, take a screenshot of the element you want to click on and follow this code:

```
Screen screen = new Screen();
Pattern properties = new Pattern(<path-to-screenshot>);
screen.wait(properties, <timeout>);
screen.click();
```

More functionality can be found in the official documentation: http://doc.sikuli.org/

I used maven to import the library:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sikulix</groupId>
    <artifactId>sikulixapi</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```